# Text is not appearing on arc donut in D3js

Tags: d3.js

Text is not appearing on the Donut Chart.Help me to fix this thing along with explanation.I am very new to D3js.

This is my sample code.

my html code is:

```
    .arc text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
   }
 .arc path {
   stroke: #fff;
  }
```

and js code is:

```
    var width = 600, height = 500, radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - 10)
            .innerRadius(radius - 70);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()

    .value(function(d) {
        return d.population;
    });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr(
            "height", height).append("g").attr("transform",
            "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    d3.csv("date.csv", type, function(error, data) {
        if (error)
            throw error;

        var g = svg.selectAll(".arc").data(pie(data)).enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc");

        g.append("path").attr("d", arc).style("fill", function(d, i) {
            return color(i);

        });

        //.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.date.age); });

        g.append("text").attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
        }).attr("dy", ".35em").text(function(d) {
            return d.date.age;
        });
    });

    function type(d) {
        d.population = +d.population;
        return d;
    }
```

csv file is
age,population
5,2704659
13,4499890
17,2159981
24,3853788

Comment: Without an example of your data, there is not enough information to help you.  Please create a bl.ocks.org, jsfiddle, or codepen of your code.

Comment: You just have a typo. Instead of `d.date.age` it has to be `d.data.age`. Here is the working code changing that letter only: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/cgen73hw/

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "typo".

Comment: Thankyou Gerardo